# Url.Action Compilation Error : BC30988: Type or 'With' expected

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I have code below, I need redirect to an other view page.

```
    function patrListClick(PAT_ID) {
        window.location.href = '<%: Url.Action("PatrList", "Patr", new { id = "_id_" }) %>'.replace('_id_', PAT_ID);
    }
```

[image]

Unfortunately, I got compilation error.
[image]

Comment: Please show your work and exception message as a text, not as an image.

Comment: @SonerGönül please see updated post. tks.

Comment: Is this function in a separate javascript file?

Comment: The error message indicates a `VB.Net` error - yet you've used C# syntax and added C# tag.  Is your website set to compile VB.Net?

Comment: @Ala Not a separate javascript file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you doing it that way,you can sort it by using `Url.Action()` and concatenating query string parameters this way:

```
function patrListClick(PAT_ID) {
   window.location.href = '<%: Url.Action("PatrList", "Patr") %>?id='+PAT_ID;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
function patrListClick(PAT_ID) {
        window.location.href = '<%: Url.Action("PatrList", "Patr", new with { .id = "_id_" }) %>'.replace('_id_', PAT_ID);
    }
```

Comment: see this link:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384915%28v=vs.90%29.aspx